# JSF 1.2 with Primefaces 3.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to use Primfaces 3.1 with JSF version 1.2?

If not which is the compatible Primfaces version for JSF 1.2.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this discussion](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3574) they decided to drop support for JSF 1.2 since version of Primefaces 2